# Clone table row using another approach by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, I am cloning a table row on icon.

For now What I have done is below:

```
<h3 class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></h3>
<table class="table">
   <tr id= "1">
        <td> <input name = "textfield" type="text" class="form-control" value = "1" > </td>
        <td> <input name= "numberfield" type="number" class="form-control" value = "2"> </td>
    </tr>


   <tr id= "3">
        <td> <input name = "textfield" type="text" class="form-control" value = "1" > </td>
        <td> <input name= "numberfield" type="number" class="form-control" value = "2"> </td>
    </tr>


   <tr id= "4">
        <td> <input name = "textfield" type="text" class="form-control" value = "1" > </td>
        <td> <input name= "numberfield" type="number" class="form-control" value = "2"> </td>
    </tr>

   <tr id = "5" class="hide">
        <td> <input name = "textfield" type="text" class="form-control" value = "1" > </td>
        <td> <input name= "numberfield" type="number" class="form-control" value = "2"> </td>           
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I cloning row by getting hidden row:

```
      var $TABLE = $('#table');

      $('.table-add').click(function () {

        var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');            
        // //Assigning every table row a unique ID
        var max=0;
        $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
            var id=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            if (id>=max){
               max = id;
             }
         });
         //cloning row with new ID  
         $clone.attr('id', parseInt(max)+1);
         $clone.find('input.myinput').tagsinput('removeAll');
         $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
      });
```

This is what I am doing- cloning a hidden row, and append to table by removing hidden class from $clone cloned row which somehow good approach as well. But I don't want something like this, I want to clone a hidden row that will be made visible now and cloned row of hidden row must
be hidden now. how to go for that.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: For older ie support you can do a `<script type="text/html">` in place of a `<template>`

Comment: what was that. my question is something else

Comment: Then I don't understand your question.  I thought you were asking for an alternate way of cloning where you didn't have to manipulate the element much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you do exactly... But, I would suggest to use a jQuery plugin to achieve that more easy. Below I put one that I used some time ago.

**jQuery Plugin to duplicate Elements:**

> https://github.com/fire1/DuplicateElement

**Live Demo:**

> http://fire1.eu/DuplicateElement/